# A java code I cant find out how it become such thing

Tags: java

I read somewhere a java code that reverse a given number. for example input is 95845 and output after compile would be 54859. My question is how this happen?

```
int num, digit;
System.out.print("please inter an INT");
num = console.nextInt()
do {
            digit = num %10;
            System.out.print(digit);
            num /= 10;
            } while(num !=0)
```

would you please explain this code for me completely?

Comment: Look up "`%` - The Modulus Operator". (Also, see what happens when entering a negative number.)

Comment: Hint:  "reversing a number" doesn't mean anything.  A number is not a thing that has a front or a back or a beginning or an end.  The thing that you are trying to reverse is the _place value representation_ of a number.  The place value representation is a sequence of _digits_ with a beginning and an end.  The thing that you want to reverse is the sequence of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your number is 123:

```
    do {
        digit = num %10;
        System.out.print(digit);
        num /= 10;
     } while(num !=0);
```

Pass1 digit = 3, it prints 3 and num = 12

Pass2 since num in pass 1 != 0, digit = 2, it prints 2 and num = 1

Pass3 since num in pass 2 != 0, digit = 1, it prints 1 and num = 0

Pass4 since num in pass 3 == 0 it leaves do while.